# How to show ProgressDialog In Android Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, progress-bar

I have some tabpages and fragments. And these fragments contain a  **GridView**   element. My program is going to webservice and reading JSON data, after getting images caching and populating gridviews custom grid.

Now, how can show ProgressDialog only not completed fragments? And how can I dismiss progressDialog GridView populating will complete?

My Fragment OnCreate Method;

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
        context = getActivity();
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Please wait, Loading Page...", true);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        if (isConnected()) {
            try {
                new ProgressTask(context).execute();
                gridView.setAdapter(new AdapterB(context, WallPaperList));
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return v;
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Please check your internet connection..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: Best option is use `AsyncTask`

Comment: May be you could use interfaces

Answer (score 0):

In AsyncTask, `create progress dialog` in `onPreExecute()` and `dismiss` that progress dialog in `onPostExecute()`.

**updated:**

add this code in your viewpager activity.

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onPageSelected(int position) {
          //You can get Call back to show the progress dialog when swipping.
          boolean isLoading = true;//Check if the fragment is still loading or not at given position.
          if (isLoading) {
                 //Show progress dialog.
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
      }
 });
```

Comment: Y not a comment ? If answer Y not a proper coded answer

Comment: accualy i try it, but not working correctly. ProgressDialog showing first and when dismissed and swipe page to fragment, i see nothing. Waiting and populated all images show to me suddenly.

Comment: After dismissing the dialog in the first fragment and swiping to the next fragment now do you want to show the progress dialog?

Comment: No first fragment is static. When user swipe page to second fragment if fragment is not ready then i want to show progressdialog.

Comment: trying right now ! Im sorry @KrishnaV how can i check fragment is still loading ?

Comment: I am sorry waiting your answer.

Comment: @EmreErol keep boolean variable in fragment, in onPageSelected get that fragment boolean and then show progress dialog based on boolean.

Answer (score 0):

its the short example for showing progress may this help you

```
 private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(DownloadImageActivity.this, "Wait", "Downloading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
          //your downloading code
        }

        /**
        * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
        * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();


            }
        }
```

Comment: accualy i try it, but not working correctly. ProgressDialog showing first and when dismissed and swipe page to fragment, i see nothing. Waiting and populated all images show to me suddenly.

Comment: because you are setting the adapter after the async task completes try to set your adapter in `onPostexecute()` method

Answer (score 0):

Check this...........

```
public interface AsyncTaskListener<Boolean> {
    public void onCompletingTask(Boolean result);
}

public class AsyncTaskGetApiKey extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{

    ArrayList<AsyncTaskListener<Boolean>> listeners;

    public AsyncTaskLoadingInSplash() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<AsyncTaskListener<Boolean>>();
    }

    public void addListener(AsyncTaskListener<Boolean> listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(AsyncTaskListener<Boolean> listener){
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //do your activities here

        return true; // If everything is fine
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        for (AsyncTaskListener<Boolean> listener:listeners) {
            listener.onReceivingApiKey(result);
        }
    }
}

public class MyFagemnt extends Fragment
implements AsyncTaskListener<Boolean>{

    AsyncTaskGetApiKey task;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //......

        task = new AsyncTaskGetApiKey();
        task.addListener(this);
        //........
    }


    @Override
    public void onCompletingTask(Boolean result) {
        // your asyntask finished 
        // now close the progress bar
    }
}
```